# How to make this camera movement smoother?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, smoothing

I am making a game where I would like the camera to be moved with a limit, I already have the script for that but I'd really like for the camera to be more smoother, If possible.

Thanks!

```
public class LimitedCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float LimitAngleX = 10f;
    public float LimitAngleY = 10f;

    private float AngleX;
    private float AngleY;
    public void Update()
    {
        var angles = transform.localEulerAngles;

        var xAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        var yAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        AngleX = Mathf.Clamp(AngleX - yAxis, -LimitAngleX, LimitAngleY);
        AngleY = Mathf.Clamp(AngleY + xAxis, -LimitAngleY, LimitAngleY);

        angles.x = AngleX;
        angles.y = AngleY;

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(angles);

        transform.localEulerAngles = angles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Solution is Multiply the `Time.deltaTime` in `InputAxis` for smoothing camera. This method inhibits frame fluctuations in the game and also makes it smoother on weaker systems.

```cs
var xAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.unscaledDeltaTime * sensitivity;
var yAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.unscaledDeltaTime * sensitivity;
```

You can also control the speed by changing the `sensitivity` variable.

```cs
public float sensitivity = 10f;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `LimitedCamera` class:

```
public static float MouseSensitivityX = 0.1f;
public static float MouseSensitivityY = 0.1f;
```

And in your `Update()` method:

```
var xAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * MouseSensitivityX;
var yAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * MouseSensitivityY;
```

You can also make sensitivity change in settings menu using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).